# Prevent duplicate entries in multiple columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I'd like to keep a user from entering a duplicate entry based off of two columns.

Ex: Column B is vendors & Column E is part number, there should be no duplicate vendor/part number combinations.

Here is all of my code:

```
' Runs events based on target changes
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Confirmation Target
    'ChangeDirectCost Target

End Sub

' Keeps user from entering the same vendor / part # twice
Private Sub Confirmation(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If (.Column <> 2 And .Column <> 5) Or .Cells.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(.Column), .Value) > 1 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .ClearContents
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            MsgBox "Vendor / Part # combination already exists!"
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Sometimes I get a type mismatch error and other times after making adjusments to the code as soon as I put a value in Column B I get the MsgBox without a value in Column E.

Initially the code was under a module but didn't work until I put it under Sheet1.

Comment: The only issue I could find is that you probably wanted to use **'... Or .Cells.Count > 1'**. Nice work.

Comment: Since you want to look for the combination, you should change your countif to a countifs, including both columns in the criteria.  I would also turn application.enableevents to false before the ClearContents then back to true after

Comment: Those changes seemed to fix it. Thank you!!!

Comment: Actually, sorry...I'm now getting my MsgBox after any addition to either column 2 or 5. It's not even waiting for me to input values into the other column. I made sure that none of my rows have blank values in case that was causing the issue. Any other suggestions...?